# CSS is not refleted in react js

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, components, reactstrap

I am trying to override the **reacstrap** components and also few html elements. But CSS is not reflected on those.Here is the component.

```
const DeleteKpiModal = ({isOpen, kpiToDelete, toggle, handleDeleteKpi}) => (
    <Modal isOpen={isOpen} toggle={() => toggle(null)}>
    <ModalBody>
      <h2 className="heading-style">Delete KPI?</h2>
    <p className="delete-content">
    Are you sure you want to delete this?
    Once deleted, the data will be lost and will not be able to be recovered.
    </p>
      </ModalBody>
    <ModalFooter className="display-button">
      <Button className="delete-button" size="md" block onClick={() => handleDeleteKpi(kpiToDelete)}>Delete</Button>
      <Button className="cancel-button" color="secondary" size="md" block  onClick={() => toggle(null)}>Cancel</Button>
    </ModalFooter>
    <style jsx>{styles}</style>
  </Modal>
  )
```

And here is the Css. Forget the imports here I am using sass/scss for doing so.

```
const styles = scss`

  @import "bootstrap-extended/jsx-import";
  $bg-red: #e04c33;

  .delete-button{
    background-color: $bg-red;
    color:#fff;
  }
  .delete-content{
    borderBottom:1px dashed #dce1e5;
    paddingBottom:3rem;
  }
  .heading-style{
    color: $bg-red;
  }
  .cancel-button{
    backgroundColor:#fff;
    color:#047adc;
    border:2px solid #047adc;
    marginLeft:0;
  }
  .display-button{
    display:initial;
    padding-top:0;
  }
`
```

Please help where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Can you provide with a codesandbox?

Comment: For this that's not possible for me. As this is a long code. Although the details I have provided is sufficient from my end.

Comment: See, the matter is about reproducing the bug too, now I can just guess that the class styles are not applying due to css specificity.

Comment: it is working if I am applying it inline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have applied like this. I make a class for upper component and used it like that.

```
<style jsx global>{`
$bg-red: #e04c33;

.delete-kpi-modal{
  .delete-button{
    background-color: $bg-red;
    color:#fff;
  }
  .delete-content{
    border-bottom:1px dashed #dce1e5;
    padding-bottom:3rem;
  }
  .heading-style{
    color: $bg-red;
    text-align:center;
  }
  .cancel-button{
    background-color:#fff;
    color:#047adc;
    border:2px solid #047adc;
    margin-left:0;
  }
  .display-button{
    display:initial;
    padding-top:0;
  }
}
`
    }
    </style>
```

And this works